# Yeast and flower for raspberries and rye beer

Tags: beer, fruit, rye

I'm thinking about making a rye/raspberries mixed beer in a 3:1 d water (basified with Mg(OH)2 to PH 6.5)/glucose ~0.1% some flower smoke (not sure what flower yet).

What yeast should I use to get a even more powerful nut/flower/fruit taste from this mixture and get a ~7% alcool percentage?
Also what flower should I burn?

My idea is to mix ~200g powdered rye in basified water and cook at 80ºC for 1h, (at room temperature) add ~30% raspberries until it forms a homogeneous solution (keeping PH), add the yeast then let the smoke sit above the liquid as soon as the fermentation ends, filter it, add agar-agar and finally filter again.

Comment: Powdered rye? You mean malted rye extract?

Comment: Are you making beer?  More detailed ingredients would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I like the fruity and florals from London Ale yeast.

Sounds fun. Let us know how it turns out.

Curious though. Why not just use rye grain and then add the smoke infused berry solution in secondary? Or smoke the grains with the flower.

Comment: i was thinking of a one fermentation method, putting everything into the solution and then seeing how the yeast reacts to it...
i think smoking the grains before fermentation can make yeast yield weird flavors maybe
i think i will use WLP830, not sure thought, any advice?

Comment: @waffletrout yeast esters are only slightly effected by ingredients. As far they effect the nutrients and sugars the yeasts consumes. Generally esters are manipulated by pitch rate, fermentation temp. Sugars effect the type of alcohol they produce, a flavor / phenol but not truley an ester.

Answer (score 1):

No hate here would love to know how this turns out.

Here is a list of Edible flowers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_edible_flowers

You could also try a Belgium yeast strain to get a nice spread of esters, that will complement your raspberries.